# Как правильно изучать Java и какими источниками пользоваться?

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! Я хочу начать изучение Java, у меня есть большой интерес к этому языку, но не знаю как его правильно изучать. Хотел спросить у опытных програмисстов совета как правильно его изучать и какими источниками пользоваться. Многие рекомендуют JavaRush, но хотелось бы узнать мнение опытных программистов. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: я отлично понимаю, что вы новый участник, но такие вопросы тут не очень любят. не советую вам задавать такие вопросы, т.к. они основаны на чьих то мнениях, а это не очень хорошо

Comment: карать я вас за это не буду, но другие вполне могут, так что осторожнее с этим

Comment: Спасибо за совет, учту в дальнейшем! @alex9127

Comment: Если совсем с нуля думаешь изучать, то JAVARUSH для старта нормально подойдет. Я с помощью этого ресурса нормально базовый синтаксис вкурил в свое время

Comment: Спасибо! @AVRamones

Comment: Полный справочник по JAVA https://goalkicker.com/JavaBook/